# 301redirect to remove folder from URL

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have:

```
mydomain.com/folder-name/segment1/segment2
```

I want to change it to:

```
mydomain.com/segment1/segment2
```

using a 301 redirect.

I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /test/$1 [L]
```

but its not working

here is my htacess file:

```
# #AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/b1/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /b1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer for the first part of the question should be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? $2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

The second code that you've tried is the opposite of what you're asking for initially. This line matches anything not starting with `/test/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/.*$
```

This line says take everything and rewrite it to the `/test/` directory:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /test/$1 [L]
```

So together anything that's not in the test directory is being rewritten to the test directory.

If you're trying to specifically remove the word test then you would remove the `!` symbol in your attempt to create a match. Since you already know it's called `test` there's no need to even make Apache perform this look for 'test' because Apache [handles the RewriteCond statement after the RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalRuleset) (rather unintuitively).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?test
```

You can specialize the rewrite rule like this (I've added `[QSA]` to catch any query strings:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? $1/$2/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It does work according to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, but Its not working for my site. I'm going to investigate further and post a new question

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your code to:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: sorry, that doesn't work the address bar still shows mydomain.com/folder-name/segment1/segment2 not mydomain.com/segment1/segment2

Comment: For changing the URL in the browser (external redirect) you will need `R` flag. I have just edited my code, try it now.

Comment: It does work according to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, but Its not working for my site. I'm going to investigate further and post a new question